# Impact of using Thead.currentThread

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, cluster-computing, threadpool

Would there be any impact of using the below snippet at commonplace which gets the frequent application control,

```
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace().HasElements
```

and

```
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()
      .hasMatch(\elt1 -> elt1.FileName == "XXXXX.java")
```

As I need to identify the control comes here from the internal batch file (XXXX.java) to perform the subsequent custom processes. Will the above snippet makes any difference in the Clustered region?

Comment: That can work... but that's quite a quirky design. Why not use runtime context/values to make that decision? Programming against source files/class names smells, at least to me. You could use tools like `ThreadLocal`s, context variables (such as in a web application) or even plain old parameters...?

Comment: Using `Thread.currentThread()` is basically irrelevant; getting a stack trace is, however, always an expensive operation.

Comment: Note also that this isn't reliable, for example, if code invoking this line is executed in a thread, you won't see the stack trace that started the thread.